# WebDav Windows Authentication on non domain join web server

Tags: iis, active-directory, windows-authentication, webdav, ntlm

Is it possible to setup IIS Webdav with windows authentication and SSL on a non domain joined web server?

The web server is hosted in azure and accessible via https 443. The clients are domain users and need to authenticate with their domain credentials in order to read/write on the web server over the internet.

My logic tells me this is not possible as the web server doesn't have a authentication provider without being domain joined?

Many thanks for any answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to use Windows Authentication, but if you have LDAP access to your AD environment from the server, you could do Forms Authentication and authenticate the user via LDAP in the back end. It would require the users to type in their credentials though.

You can test access to any one of the LDAP ports in PowerShell with:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName domain.com -Port 389
```

The LDAP ports are:

- 389: LDAP
- 636: LDAP over SSL
- 3268: Global Catalog - same as LDAP but reads the whole AD forest
- 3269: GC over SSL

Any one of those would do.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! By form authentication you mean a web form and back end coding for authenticating against the ad? Or do you mean that credentials are enough, so that the shared web dav can be added as a drive?

Comment: We need some kind of ldap authentication without the need to enter credentials. A mapped drive where the credentials are entered one time is also ok.

Comment: I mean a web form and back end coding for authenticating against AD. None of the built-in AD authentication methods (NTLM or Kerberos) will work if the server is not joined to a domain (either the same domain, or a trusted domain).